# How to chain includes in Jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, include, pug

I am using the Jade template engine in node.js Express. If we wish to include another Jade file in a Jade file, we can do the following:

```
exports.overview = function(req, res, next) { 
  var jade = require('jade');
  res.render('A', {
     main: jade.renderFile('./views/B.jade')
  });
};
```

My question is: what if we wish to chain the includes to more than 2 files? Suppose A.jade includes B.jade, which in turn includes C.jade. I was thinking we can do this:

```
exports.overview = function(req, res, next) { 
  var jade = require('jade');
  res.render('A', {
     main: jade.renderFile('./views/B.jade',{
        carousel: jade.renderFile('./views/C.jade')
     })
  });
};
```

Apparently it won't work. What should we do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget that you can also do includes directly within the Jade file, or simply use `jade.render` on a string of Jade formatted includes (such as the below contents of includes.jade). It doesn't seem like there's a good reason do recursive includes as you do in the example. Just add the include as needed in the Jade file itself.

Something like:

```
exports.overview = function(req, res, next) { 
  var jade = require('jade');
  res.render('A', {
     main: jade.renderFile('./views/includes.jade')
  });
};
```

### includes.jade

```
include ./views/B.jade
include ./views/C.jade
include ./views/D.jade
include ./views/E.jade
```

Alternatively, you could probably use a for-loop.